# discord.errors.HTTPException: 405 Method Not Allowed (error code: 0): 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: discord, discord.py, http-status-code-405

I am making a discord bot that reacts to images sent by users with an appropriate emoji/reaction that is determined by a CLIP model, it all works perfectly until I try to react to a message with m output. I can send the emojis as replys or messages but if I try to react to a message with the emoji I get the errror:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 405 Method Not Allowed (error code: 0): 405: Method Not Allowed
```

The code I'm trying to execute is:

```
file_ = filename
print("classifying")
reaction = classify(file_)
print(reaction)
await message.channel.send(reaction)
```

and this code always returns something like this when I try to send it to a channel without it being a reaction:

```
classifying
⛲️
```

any suggestions to get it to use these emojis as an actual reaction within the discord.py API?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the output of your classification is a [Unicode Emoji](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), we can simply use the `add_reaction` method.

```py
    file_ = filename
    reaction = classify(file_)

    await message.add_reaction(reaction)
```

In the above example, our `message` variable is an instance of the [Message Class](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message).

Comment: That's the issue, the emoji is Unicode but every time I run the message.add_reaction I get the error

Comment: In that case, could you please edit your question to include more specific details about what code you're running? This would allow me to run your code on my machine and work towards fixing your issue.